# f-measure,precision and recall does does not seem reasonable

Tags: weka

I run weka and I am using decision tree and Naive base but both result the same as follow:

```
Precision:   0.0   Recall:   0.0 F-measure :    0.0   accuracy:   72.4867724867725 True positive: 0.0 False positive: 0.0 True negative: 137.0 False negative: 52.0
```

The thing is I do not understand why the precisoin recall and f measure are all 0...

does anyone have any idea?

Comment: To clarify the question, what is the task? Presumably binary classification? It makes sense that precision, recall, and f measure/f1 score are all 0 if your TP count is 0, since each measure makes use of TP in the numerator. Perhaps you are asking about why your models predict no positives?

Comment: Yes exactly also  I am using decision tree and NB both

Comment: Can you provide a description of the dataset you are working with, and perhaps some sample training examples? It may be the case that you are working with a very skewed training set with very, very few positive examples.